# Ranges of x for a curve $\frac{-(2 x_1-2 x_0) \pm \sqrt{\max(0,(2 x_1-2 x_0)^2 - 4(x_0 - 2 x_1 + x_2)(x_0 - x)})}{2 (x_0 - 2x_1 + x_2)}$ in a rectange

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There is a curve $$y = \frac{-(2 x_1 - 2 x_0) \pm \sqrt{max(0, (2 x_1 - 2 x_0)^2 - 4(x_0 - 2 x_1 + x_2)(x_0 - x)})}{2 (x_0 - 2x_1 + x_2)})^2 (y_0 - 2 y_1 + y_2)+ \frac{-(2 x_1 - 2 x_0) \pm \sqrt{max(0, (2 x_1 - 2 x_0)^2 - 4(x_0 - 2 x_1 + x_2)(x_0 - x)})}{2 (x_0 - 2x_1 + x_2)}) (2 y_1 - 2 y_0) + y_0$$
[image: example curve]
that consist of two functions
$$f_{+}(x) = \frac{-(2 x_1 - 2 x_0) + \sqrt{max(0, (2 x_1 - 2 x_0)^2 - 4(x_0 - 2 x_1 + x_2)(x_0 - x)})}{2 (x_0 - 2x_1 + x_2)})^2 (y_0 - 2 y_1 + y_2)+ \frac{-(2 x_1 - 2 x_0) + \sqrt{max(0, (2 x_1 - 2 x_0)^2 - 4(x_0 - 2 x_1 + x_2)(x_0 - x)})}{2 (x_0 - 2x_1 + x_2)}) (2 y_1 - 2 y_0) + y_0$$ and $$f_{-}(x) = \frac{-(2 x_1 - 2 x_0) - \sqrt{max(0, (2 x_1 - 2 x_0)^2 - 4(x_0 - 2 x_1 + x_2)(x_0 - x)})}{2 (x_0 - 2x_1 + x_2)})^2 (y_0 - 2 y_1 + y_2)+ \frac{-(2 x_1 - 2 x_0) - \sqrt{max(0, (2 x_1 - 2 x_0)^2 - 4(x_0 - 2 x_1 + x_2)(x_0 - x)})}{2 (x_0 - 2x_1 + x_2)}) (2 y_1 - 2 y_0) + y_0$$
for each function I need to find ranges of x that:

1. y is between $y_{min}$ and $y_{max}$
2. y is under $y_{min}$
3. y is over $y_{max}$

Comment: You should write the original problem. What you've written is some intermediate step while performing calculations.

Comment: The closing parentheses immediately following the two fractions have no matching open parentheses. It is unclear where the opening parentheses should be (at least the second one - the first has only one place it could be sensibly put without making other changes).

Comment: Did you apply the quadratic formula to $(x_0-2x_1+x_2)t^2+(2x_1-2x_0)t+(x_0-x)=0$ (where $t$ is another variable)? To me, the expression for the curve looks like an instance of the quadratic formula.

Comment: Also - here are some **really helpful tricks**: (1) Simplify: get rid of that factor of two that you have in both the numerator and denominator. (2) replace complicated *constant* expressions with simple constants: $$A = x_0 -2x_1 + x_2, B = x_0 - x_1, C = y_0 -2y_1 + y_2, D = 2y_1 -2y_0$$ (3) Introduce intermediary functions: $$z = \frac {B + \sqrt{\max\{0, B^2 - A(x_0 - x)\}}}A$$Then you can solve for $z_{min}, z_{max}$ first fairly easily, and then solve for $x_{min}, x_{max}$ in terms of $z_{min}, z_{max}$.

Comment: @Maverick the ORIGINAL problem is from associated with Bezier curves but it is not the point I have this curve which is equvalent to a NON LINEAR quadratic bezier. But the "original" problem is finding the common field of this curve (area between 2 functions) and a square but i decided to generalize to a rectangle. I got the atiderivative of two functions and now I need to know for what ranges of x apply 0, x*height or definite integral |f(x)| - x*y_min)